# Ecommerce database design, save product information without affecting historical data

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

What would be the best, if not, the practical way to design an e-commerce database wherein the product information of the product purchased by a customer should not update when the product information was updated?

To give a better understanding, here's a scenario:

1. Merchant created "Product A" where it is priced at $50.
2. Customer saw Product A and purchased it.
3. Customer visited the transaction history and viewed his recent purchase: Product A priced at $50
4. Month's after, Merchant updated the price of Product A to $80.
5. Customer viewed again his transaction history. His transaction with Product A should retain at $50 and not the updated price of $80 because it was the price he paid that time.

One solution I am looking into is to save the whole product information in a table as a PHP serialized data in "purchases.product_information".

Is it even a good idea to store PHP serialized data in a column? How's performance if a user wanted to search for a text in the product information like price, item name, etc.?

Any other workaround for this?

Thank you

Comment: `Is it even a good idea to store PHP serialized data in a column? How's performance if a user wanted to search for a text in the product information like price, item name, etc.?`  That is the trade off, that said there is some new support for JSON in MySql etc...  Just depends how you plan to use the data.  In other words you can save data like that Wordpress does it all the time with meta data, but it's less then Ideal to search on it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a case of slowly changing dimensions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension)

A simple solution will be to have a separate table purchase_items and have all the columns that may change over time against each item (Example:price, discount etc) and purchase and purchase_items table will have one_to_many relationship

Although, there are more complex situations where the price of the product changes on the fly based on the time at which an order is made in a day etc. In these cases, the price may not be stored against the product itself

This answer is addresses exactly the issue and you might find this helpful
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57992/ecommerce-orders-table-save-prices-or-use-an-audit-history-table